# Dictionary English - logic/formal symbols/expresssions

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, terminology

I'd like to know whether there's some kind of database offering the logic or formal" equivalent of English expressions, for example the conjunction "whereas", which has at least two meanings, each meaning in turn having several synonyms.

So far, I've only found the three pages below

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols

https://unicode-table.com/en/

Comment: NO; you have found already the List of logical symbols with their (English) language counterpart. The vice versa is much more difficult to summarize: not every natural language expression has a "logic or formal equivalent".